# Cross-reference for Figure

Tags: cross-referencing

What is the difference between the following as the outcome is the same.

```
 \begin{figure}[h!]
     \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figures/PilotStudy.png}
     \caption{Test
     \label{fig:Test}
    }
 \end{figure}
```

AND

```
 \begin{figure}[h!]
     \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figures/PilotStudy.png}
     \caption{Test}
     \label{fig:Test}
 \end{figure}
```

Both give the same outcome

Comment: That's right. It's the same result.

Comment: @Bernard, why they put the { different outcome same

Comment: @Bernard The outcome is *not* (precisely) the same. The first version adds a spurious space. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
     \centering
   \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
     \caption{Test
     \label{fig:Test1}
    }
 \end{figure}
\setcounter{figure}{0} 
 \begin{figure}[h!]
     \centering
   \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
     \caption{Test}
     \label{fig:Test2}
 \end{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw (current page.north) -- (current page.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat, Thanks. I saw a difference in the alignment. But in terms of cross-referencing, is work well for both right?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: it adds 0.7pt, because you left   blank spaces in the argument of \caption (on each side of `\label{fig:Test1}`).

Comment: @Bernard, I tried this `\caption{Test \label{fig:Test1}}`. But there is still some slightly different, around 0.05cm, is not obvious. What we want is to make the cross-referencing is working well.

Comment: @Bernard I only copied the code from the OP.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: I didn't mean it was you, personally, of course. Anyway for me, the difference is inappreciable to ordinary eyes.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, what is ‘OP’?

Comment: @aan The Original Poster, in this case: you